# Calculate length of sequence - SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms-agnostic

I have a table consists **person id (id)** and a **flight date (date)**.
Each person may have few flights in different dates. If 2 flights are a week or less apart, they are considered the **same trip**.
For example, for person id #2: 2022-05-20 -> 2022-05-23 -> 2022-05-29 is a trip with 3 flights.
I would like to calculate, for each person, the length of their trips (3 for the example above).

```
id  | flight_date
2   | 2022-05-20
2   | 2022-05-23
2   | 2022-05-29
1   | 2022-04-01
1   | 2022-05-03
3   | 2022-04-15
3   | 2022-04-22
```

The output for the example would be something like:

```
id | trip_length
2  | 3
1  | 1 (beacuse his 2 trips are not a week apart)
3  | 2
```

I have tried to use group by for this, but I can't calculate it with the time constraint (a week between each flight).

Would appreciate any help.
Thank you very much!

SQL dialect is not much important :)

Comment: "_If 2 flights are a week or less apart, they are considered the same trip._" - having which date? (First or last?)

Comment: the date of the trip is not important - I just want to count how many flights are in a trip @jarlh

Comment: Use window functions.  On the first pass, use `lag()` to mark when a new trip starts (no previous flight within seven days).  On the second pass, use `sum()` to assign numbers to the trips.  On the third pass, use `count()` to get the length of the trips.  On the last pass, use a regular `group by` to get the max trip length per person.

Comment: But Id 2's first two trips are during the same week, so I assume they should be considered as one single trip?

Comment: @jarlh What do you mean?

Comment: @MikeOrganek Fantastic! Will try that.